# How to load array of Labels or other types into fxml scene?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

i'm writing simple VBox with complited array of Labels, but i don't understand how to add that array.
List.fxml

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="list.ListController">
    <List>
        <fx:reference source="list"/>
    </List>
</VBox>
```

ListController.java

```
//It's a test code...
package list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ListController {
    public List<Label> list = new ArrayList<Label>(Arrays.asList(new Label("Test"), new Label("Test2")));
    
}
```

Compiler err:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/giglo/eclipse-workspace/YourList/bin/List.fxml:10

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1011)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at list.Input.start(Input.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Exception running application list.Input
```

That code is best of more versions becouse i spent a lot of time searching for fx:... and variable classes.
But his don't work.
I understand that javafx itself will not figure out what to do with my List, but I do not know how to tell it what to do with my List.

Answer (score 3):

## Problems

There are a few problems with this setup.

### Interface as Element Type

You are telling the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) *directly*. This is not possible, because that type is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated. You would have to use a concrete implementation, such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

This problem is where your current error is coming from:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.List
>         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
>         ... 15 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
>         at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
> ```

### Incorrect Reference

You are referencing the list incorrectly. Because the list is from the controller, it should look like:

```xml
<fx:reference source="controller.list"/>
```

But it will still complain about that value not existing. The `FXMLLoader` does not do field access when trying to *get* a value. It looks for an appropriate getter method instead. For instance, here we're telling the loader to get the `list` property of the controller instance, and so it looks for a `getList()` method in the controller class. So, that method needs to exist.

```java
public List<Label> getList() {
    return list;
}
```

### Adding List to "Read-Only List Property"

***Warning:** This problem would seem to make your approach impractical, if not impossible.*

You are trying to populate the `children` list of the `VBox`. That list is known as a ["read-only list property"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#read_only_list_property_elements). Unfortunately, the linked documentation says nothing about being able to add a *collection* to such properties (e.g., via `addAll`):

> A read-only list property is a Bean property whose getter returns an instance of `java.util.List` and has no corresponding setter method. The contents of a read-only list element are automatically added to the list as they are processed.
>
> For example, the "children" property of `javafx.scene.Group` is a read-only list property representing the group's child nodes:
>
> ```xml
> <?import javafx.scene.*?>
> <?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
> <Group xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
>     <children>
>         <Rectangle fx:id="rectangle" x="10" y="10" width="320" height="240"
>             fill="#ff0000"/>
>         ...
>     </children>
> </Group>
> ```
>
> As each sub-element of the `<children>` element is read, it is added to the list returned by `Group#getChildren()`.

And trying it out, you get an error like the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce [[Label@15af0be5[styleClass=label]'Foo', Label@49a4edc6[styleClass=label]'Bar']] to class javafx.scene.Node.
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:497)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.add(FXMLLoader.java:174)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:801)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2969)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2654)
        ... 17 more
```

<sup>(i.e., it could not cast `List<Node>` to `Node`)</sup>

---

## A Solution

If you want to keep the list of labels defined in your controller, then you can simply add those labels to the `VBox` in the `initialize` method.

```java
package list;

import java.util.List;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class ListController {

    private final List<Label> list = List.of(new Label("Foo"), new Label("Bar"));

    @FXML
    private VBox box;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        box.getChildren().addAll(list);
    }
}
```

This of course requires adding an appropriate `fx:id` attribute in the FXML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="box" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" 
      fx:controller="list.ListController">
</VBox>
```

Note that `List::of` returns an unmodifiable list. Modifying this list would not make much sense anyway, at least not after adding the elements to the `VBox`'s children list, as modifying it would *not* implicitly modify the children list. If labels can be added and removed, then you'll have to make sure the two lists are in sync (as well as use a modifiable list). In that case, it may make more sense to use an `ObservableList<Label>` and [bind the children list's content](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent(java.util.List,javafx.collections.ObservableList)), assuming the `VBox` only contains those labels.

Comment: That is, there is no other way but to add the contents to the list by the method in the controller?

Comment: Not if you want to instantiate the list of labels in the controller. At least, there's not a way that I can think of. That said, you can `fx:define` the list in the FXML file, as well as each label. But if I'm not mistaken, you'll have to have an `fx:reference` in the list _and_ the vbox's children, _for each label_ (i.e., two references per label). That doesn't seem very practical/maintainable. Why do you need this preallocated `List<Label>` in the first place? Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/609787).

Comment: Regarding "why do I need a List<Label>" - in general, the data will be stored in a JsonArray, and I need to automatically load the Label array into the VBox. Yes, I have already seen the solution with fx:Id="vbox", but as for me, it does not make sense to separate a piece of small code (several dozen lines) in fx:controller if you can implement it in the same place as the rest of the code( in fxml). 
In fact, this is not the first time I have encountered the complexity of banal things, at least in terms of finding information. Or I'm just bad at searching and often ask for help ..

Comment: An FXML file should only be used to define the static (i.e., non-changing) parts of the view, while the controller should handle any dynamic parts of the view. Loading in data and displaying it in the view is dynamic. And then there are some things that are just easier to do in the controller (e.g., setting the cell factories or cell-value factories of list views, table views, etc.). So, since data is being "stored" in a JsonArray, which implies the data is being loaded from a JSON file, adding the labels sounds like it _should be done in the controller_ anyway.

Comment: As an aside, a `VBox` containing an arbitrarily large and variable number `Label`s might be better implemented as a `ListView<String>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations.